# Static variation Vs Dynamic Variation in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: oop

I know for static variation we use inheritance and for dynamic we use Object composition. Can someone provide me short examples whether how Object composition is Dynamic and Inheritance is  Static?

Comment: google buddy.. google

Comment: Googled, but could not find anything :(

Comment: What do you mean by “variation”?

Answer (score 0):

A Component(module) can be replaced, removed, or added at runtime (dynamic binding). On the contrary, inheritance can't or very hard (depending on the programming language) to be replaced, removed, or added features at runtime (static binding).Please refer below link for example [link]http://www.kbasm.com/oop-prefer-composition-over-inheritance.html